# SQL Query can not run after stored-procedure call in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

**In My php code i call stored-procedure before Normal SQL (link : SELECT * FROM `TABLE`;) Query run. for that stored-procedure run but Normal SQL can-not run. I use mysql_query() in both case. but when i run normal SQL it run both time.**

I have a class dataManager that have the mysql_query()

here is my code :

> ```
> require_once 'DL/DataManager.php'; 
> require_once 'utils/Utils.php';
> require_once 'DL/class/event/Event.php';
> ```

```
$Utils = new Utils();
$obj = new Event();

$result = array();

$result = $obj->get_all_event_data("NULL"); //Query =  "CALL events_all_data(" . $ID . ");";

echo date("y-m-d h:i:s")."<br />";

echo $Utils->getString_UserName_ByUserID( "23" )."<br />"; // Not Run   Query = SELECT  `USER_NICK` FROM  `USER_INFO` WHERE  `USER_ID` ='".$string ."';";
```

**DataManager.php**

> ```
> public function openConnection()
> {
>     $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->HostName, $this->UserName, $this->PassWord);
>         if (!$this->connection)
>         {
>                 return mysql_error();
>         }
>         mysql_select_db($this->DataBase);
>         return $this->connection;
> }
> ```

**execute sql query**

```
public function retrieveData($Query = "")
{
    //$Query = mysql_real_escape_string($Query);
    //echo "DB retriveData query : ".$Query. " <br />";
    $data = mysql_query($Query);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($data);
    //echo "db ret number : ".$num_rows." asdas: ". "\n";


    if($num_rows)
    {
        $this->Data = array();
        //$i = 0;
        while ($mat[] = mysql_fetch_row($data));
            //echo $mat[$i++][2]."<br />";
        $this->Data = $mat;
        //print_r($this->Data);
    //$result = $this->getArrayTranspose($mat);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Data = NULL;
    }

    //return $result;

}
```

**Connection Close**

```
public function closeConnection()
{
    if(!$this->connection)
    {
        mysql_close ();

        return ;
    }
    else if($this->connection == NULL)
    {
        mysql_close ();

        return ;
    }
    else if(!isset($this->connection))
    {
        mysql_close ();

        return ;
    }
    else if(is_resource($this->connection))
    {
        mysql_close($this->connection);
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        //mysql_close();
    }

}
```

Comment: which driver are you using for connection mysqli/mysql?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you did not mention anywhere that what is `$string`
Try to run query like this to get error code.

```
 $mat=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Give it a try.

Comment: mysql_error()give me this Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Answer (score 0):

Mysql Error is: **Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**